# React, Redux, how response data will be available in all the components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am using react and redux, api returns data. How data written in `useDispatch` will be available in other components.

How `customerId` will be available in all the components. I created a code that is calling api and data is returned in response. I also created a reducer. Not sure how to do this, so that `customerId` will be available.

```
{

    "sessionId": "5f9f0de7-c7b3-3029",
    "customerId": "410742",
    "recepientId": "122",

    "keyPropertiesList": [
        {
            "id": 267076,

            "properties": {

                "customer1": {

                    "firstName": "test",

                    "lastName": "A",

                    "fullName": "test A”

                },

                "userDetail": {

                    "userId": "3770930",

                    "name": "Sam"

                },

                "locationID": "03144"

            }

        }

    ],

    "timeStamp": "2023-05-19T06:12:32Z"

}
const test = () => {
  const [sessionInfo, setsessionInfo] = useState(useSelector(state => state.app.DataReducer.sessionDetails));

  const uDispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    sessionInformation();

    async function sessionInformation() {
      const session_ID = '5f9f0de7-c7b3-3029'

      console.log("sessionInformaiton: " + session_ID)

      await SessionInformationService({ sessionId: session_ID })
        .then((result) => {
          console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));

          if (result.data !== undefined) {
            setsessionInfo(result.data);
          }
        });
    }

    uDispatch(types.updateData({
      sessionDetails: {
        customerId: sessionInfo.customerId,
          customerfirstName: sessionInfo.firstName,
          customerlastName: sessionInfo.lastName,
          customerfullName: sessionInfo.fullName,
        }
      })
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <>

    </>
  )
};

export default test;
```

reducer

```js
import * as types from './action';

export const initialState = {
  sessionDetails: {
    customerId: '',
    customerfirstName: '',
    customerlastName: '',
    customerfullName: ''
  }
}

const Datareducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_DATA:
      const output = action.payload;

      if (output.sessionDetails) {
        state.sessionDetails = output.sessionDetails;
      }

      return {
        ...state,
      }
      break;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default Datareducer;
```

action.js

```js
export const UPDATE_DATA = 'UPDATE_DATA';

export const updateData = payload => ({
  type: UPDATE_DATA,
  payload
});
```

Comment: *Where* do you want to access `customerId` or the `sessionDetails` state? Or is that the question, how to access the redux state?

Comment: I want to access sessionDetails objector sessionDetails data outside of this component. I want this information to be available in the other components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue to resolve is the state mutation in the reducer function.

`state.sessionDetails = output.sessionDetails;` mutates the current state object. Shallow copy the previous state reference *then* override properties. See [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) for more details.

```js
const dataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_DATA:
      const { sessionDetails } = action.payload;

      if (sessionDetails) {
        return {
          ...state,
          sessionDetails: {
            ...state.sessionDetails,
            ...sessionDetails,
          }
        };
      }

      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The second issue is that the `Test` component isn't managing fetching data and updating the store correctly. It's caching a copy of the `sessionDetails` state from redux in a `sessionInfo` local state variable, but the `useEffect` is simultaneously fetching the session data *and* dispatching the `updateData` action that just sends the unupdated `sesstionInfo` local state back to the store. Effectively the Redux state isn't updated with populated data.

There's no need for the local `sessionInfo` state, the `useEffect` hook and fetch and dispatch the data directly.

React components are also use PascalCase names, `test` isn't a valid React component, but `Test` is. Rename the function component.

```
const Test = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const sessionInformation = async () => {
      const sessionId = '5f9f0de7-c7b3-3029';

      console.log("sessionInformaiton: ", sessionId);

      try {
        const { data } = await SessionInformationService({ sessionId });

        console.log("Result: ", { data });

        if (data) {
          const userData = {
            sessionDetails: {
              customerId: data.customerId,
              firstName: data.customerfirstName,
              lastName: data.customerlastName,
              fullName: data.customerfullName,
            }
          };

          dispatch(types.updateData(userData));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // handle any errors, if necessary, or ignore, your call
      }
    };
 
    sessionInformation();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Use the [`useSelector`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) hook to access the state. The selector functions follows the state structure that is formed by combining the reducers.

Example:

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

...

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { customerId } = useSelector(
    state => state.app.DataReducer.sessionDetails
  );

  ...
};
```

Comment: There is an issue. customerId value is coming from response in both components. But all the other data like firstName, lastName, fullName values are not coming from response, if the data is nested inside json then, with data.firstName value is not coming.  Added the json response with the question.

Comment: @sarad The data, it looks like `customerId` is `data. customerId` and all other data is nested in `data.keyPropertiesList[0].properties.customer1`.